# Unique sequential reservation code

Tags: functions, theme-development

I have a situation where I'm re building a tour transfer reservation site, I've created the reservations cpt's and each time a user place a reservations this automatically post as a new reservation.

Now I need a better way to locate each reservation with a unique number, another situation is that the previous system already had a sequential number so I will need this code to have an starting point, example:

> previous system last number: 3000
>
> new wp system starting point: 3001
>
> new reservation: 3002
>
> new reservation: 3003
>
> and so on...

I have a vague idea on how to achieve this. Create a custom field for reservation code, each time a reservation is placed check for the last post reservation field and increment by one, but i don't know if this is the best way to do so.

Comment: I would have stored that value in a theme_setting, it's simpler in my opinion. More informations [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

Comment: which one, the initial sequence number or the latest reservation to follow?

Comment: The sequence number and then you could increment it using a add_action('save_post')

Comment: Ok, I'm not really sure if I'll get it hehe, but I will give a try. If you could maybe give an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution among others :

In a plugin, you create an option on it's activation in order to store your sequence number :

```
/*
Plugin Name: Reservation Increment
Description: test
*/


/**
*
* Name : myplugin_activate
* Description : Activation function
*
* @params
* @return 
*
**/

function myplugin_activate() {
    update_option('reservation_increment',3000);
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );
```

Now you have to update that value and associate it with your new CPT when you create a new reservation :

```
/**
*
* Name : update_reservation_sequence
* Description : Updates the reservation unique incremential number
*
* @params
* @return 
*
**/
function update_reservation_sequence ($post_id, $post, $update){

    $slug = 'reservation_cpt';

    // If this isn't a 'reservation_cpt' post, don't update it.
    if ( $slug != $post->post_type  || $update) {
        return;
    }

    $increment = get_option('reservation_increment') +1;

    if ( ! add_post_meta( $post_id, 'reservation', $increment, true ) ) { 
       update_post_meta ( $post_id, 'reservation', $increment );
    }

    update_option('reservation_increment',$increment);

    return;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'update_reservation_sequence',10,3 );
```

And then, to access it in your single-reservation.php template :

```
echo "<p>Reservation number : ".get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'reservation', true )."</p>";
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I was struggling trying to get this.